# Concentration inequality of $L$-Lipschitz function of Gaussian Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, lipschitz-functions, concentration-of-measure

Define $W \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ as a matrix where each component $W_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is i.i.d. and suppose I have some function $f$ that is $L$-Lipschitz, ie for any $W, \hat{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ we have that

$$| f(W) - f(\hat{W})| \leq L \lVert W - \hat{W} \rVert_F$$

I want to show that the following concentration result holds

$$P(f(W) - \mathbb{E}_{W}\left[f(W)\right] \geq t) \leq \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2 L^2}\right)$$

I bring this up because I was reading a paper that implies this result. The snippet from the paper is the following:

[image: lipschitz concentration from paper]

I spent some time looking through the common concentration inequalities and I did not see anything that quite easily allows us to arrive at the concentration inequality implied in the paper. The concentration somewhat reminds me of the bound that might come if $f(W)$ was sub-gaussian in parameter $L$, but I am not sure if this is the right way to view the situation.

If there is a well known concentration inequality that I can use to investigate this, I would love to know!

Comment: Theorem 8 in these notes (https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/254a-notes-1-concentration-of-measure/) seems to be relevant. He doesn't state the explicit constants in the theorem, but mentions them in the discussion afterwards if I remember correctly.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Thank you for that link! I read through it a bit and it was informative. I used it to also find some better keywords in my search online and I actually found some notes at MIT that mention the theorem I was looking for! I'm going to look at the derivation now because apparently to get the exact bound I am looking for, one has to work a bit.